# Нейро сети keras. Изменить логику обучения

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras

Мне необходимо изменить логику метода fit в keras. Как я понял метод fit делает предсказание, и сравнивает его с правильным ответом. Вот эту функцию я бы хотел взять на себя. Делать свою реализацию нейросети не очень хочется, но если другого выхода нет то буду ее делать.

Comment: А что именно должна делать ваша версия метода .fit() ?

Comment: Она будет так же сверять данные, но будет форматировать предсказание в другой формат. Мне так нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `.fit()` предназначен для обучения модели - нахождения оптимальных весов нейронной сети (НС). Если вы измените данный метод, то НС, с высокой степенью вероятности, перестанет правильно обучаться или будет делать это гораздо хуже.

Для предсказания используются методы `.predict()` и `.predict_proba()`.

Comment: Подскажите как можно изменить этот метод. Я понимаю все риски

Comment: @mazda3301, ну тогда берёте исходники Keras и вперёд ;)